# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, advice

> Let $r,s,t\in\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that
>   $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$.

Ok. So I've fallen a little behind in my algebra class, and I'm a bit confused on how to approach this problem. I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})=\{a+b\sqrt{t}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. So I'm assuming that I need to show $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})$. However, I'm unsure of how to go about defining $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})$ as a set.

Another approach I am considering is to show that $\sqrt{t}$ and $r+s\sqrt{t}$       have the same minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. This would prove that $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$, which may get me some where closer to where I need to be.

Please steer me in the correct direction. I prefer advice to answers. Thank you in advance for your help.

Additional info: If $K$ is a field and $F$ is a subfield of $K$ and $u\in K$, then $F(u)$ is the **simple extension** of $F$ - the intersection of all subfields of $K$ that contain both $u$ and $F$. So, in my problem, I'm assuming that $K=\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$. I also know that $u$ is the root of a unique monic irreducible polynomial (called the minimal polynomial of $u$) in $F[x]$- the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: $$\mathbb Q[r + s\sqrt{t}] := \{c +d(r + s\sqrt{t}) : c, d \in \mathbb Q \}$$

Comment: @user222031 That's it? I was considering defining $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})$ like that, but I didn't think that it was that easy. Why is this true? Is there a definition or a theorem that says we can do this?

Comment: @Skull-Face You're going to have to tell us what definitions your class is working from. As far as I'm concerned, what user222031 gave is the *definition* of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ - but your class might be doing things in a different order. What do you understand $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ to mean?

Comment: @Billy I just added some more info to my post.

Comment: I see. That object that user222031 is defining isn't *a priori* a field (note the use of square brackets rather than round brackets - in general, $F(u)$ and $F[u]$ are different things), but it happens to be in this case. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is false when $s = 0$ and $t$ is not a square, for obvious reasons. So suppose $s\neq 0$.

By definition, $\mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})$ is some field (actually, the smallest) containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $r+s\sqrt{t}$. But if it contains $\mathbb{Q}$, then in particular it contains $r$ and $s$. Now:

- as it contains $r+s\sqrt{t}$ and $r$ and it's a field, we may subtract one from the other to show that it contains $s\sqrt{t}$;
- as it contains $s\sqrt{t}$ and $s\neq 0$, we may divide one by the other to show that it contains $\sqrt{t}$.

To sum up, it's a field, and it contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{t}$: that is, it must feature somewhere in the big intersection of fields that defines $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$, so we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(r+s\sqrt{t})$.

The converse is basically identical. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$ contains $\sqrt{t}$, which I can multiply by $s$ and then add $r$ to to show that it contains $r+s\sqrt{t}$.

(Sorry for writing up a full answer, but I felt that any hint I could give would give all the details away anyway!)

Comment: Thanks. I have some other problems like this, so your answer gives me insight into those as well.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $s\neq 0$

$r+s\sqrt t \in \mathbb Q(r+s\sqrt t) \implies s\sqrt t\in \mathbb Q(r+s\sqrt t)\implies \sqrt t\in \mathbb Q(r+s\sqrt t)$ since $s\neq 0$

Now $\mathbb Q(\sqrt t)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt t$

Thus $\mathbb Q(\sqrt t)\subset \mathbb Q(r+s\sqrt t)$

similarly $r,s,\sqrt t\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt t)\implies r+s\sqrt t \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt t)\implies \mathbb Q(r+s\sqrt t)\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt t)$